# How to check the performance of a new logging infrastructure

Tags: c#, .net, logging, inversion-of-control, log4net

I want to replace our current logging and use `PolicyInjection` with `[Log]` attributes above each method.

I want to log entrance and exit from each such method.

I have two requirements, and would appreciate you advice:

1. Performance check - How should I do it? If I write a POC, it would be without stress check. Is there any ready made creative way to check logging performance?
2. Make sure log level doesn’t require application restart - is it possible? I know only changing config in web.config which results in an application restart.

Answer (score 0):

as for (2) Log4net config does the work. Changing without application restart

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4netConfig.config", Watch = true)]
```